# Is it possible to pass a request header on a link with EJS template? Express/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm a trying to make a route accessible only if you are authenticated with JWT using below middleware but I can't seem to find a way to pass the token in the get request from client side ?
It works fine on postman and I if using a fetch from client side it won't redirect me to the page I want to go

auth.js

```
async function (req, res, next) {
  const token = req.header('x-auth-token');

  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Forbidden' });
  }

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);

    req.user = decoded.user;

    next();
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(401).json({ err: 'fail' });
  }
};
```

server side

```
router.get('/', auth, function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('pages/person');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply attach your `token` to the `headers` in the request and sent it with `get` or even 'delete` method.

for example, in the `fetch` method you can attach your token in this way in your client side:

```
fetch('URL_GOES_HERE', { 
   method: 'post', 
   headers: new Headers({
     'Authorization': YOUR_TOKEN, 
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   }), 
 });
```

Now, you can retrieve the token in the node app:

```
const token = req.headers.authorization || "";
```

Comment: That's what I thought, then I am just going to hide the link and have the verification done inside the page. Thanks.